# Background tasks in Openfire

Tags: openfire

I'm new to Openfire, coming from some apps developed with Google Firebase. Can openfire do some background tasks by its own, like reading data from a webservice on a time base and then push notifications to connected clients?

Thanks in advance, regards

Answer (score 0):

Openfire has a plugin mechanism, exposing its internal API, that you can utilize to make it do pretty much whatever you want. You will have provide the implementation yourself though.

Comment: Many thanks, mr Guus, I will try to dig deeper into the system